# Gradient Mask on Horizontally Scrolling Navigation

Tags: css

I have created a pure `css` Horizontally scrolling navigation. I'm trying to apply a gradient mask although I am unsure how I would apply it once I scroll the navigation into the overflow.

As per this screenshot, it works fine initially, but once I scroll..

[image]

Once the `div` is scrolled into the overflow content

[image]

```css
.topnav {
  display: none;
  min-width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.topnav div {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
 .topnav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: color 0.3s;

  }

  .topnav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="mytopnav" class="topnav">
  <div>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Packages</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Blog</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have omitted some `js` and other components for my navigation but just provided the crucial pieces.

I kinda need someone to point me in the right direction of somehow applying a mask in front of the navigation items

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, the mask-image property has a very bad browser support:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

What would be a better option, in my opinion, is to create an overlay div with the gradient and move your navigation items outside it.

```
<div id="mytopnav" class="topnav">
  <div class="gradient-overlay></div>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Packages</a>
    <a class="navitem" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="navitem"href="#">Blog</a>
    <a class="navitem"href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
```

After that, you can just say:

```
.gradient-overlay {
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

This will create an gradient above your navigation items and you can just scroll without scrolling the gradient as well.

Comment: I've managed to solve it in the end, I feel kind of silly for not managing to realise earlier! Thanks for your note on the browser support, I will try your method and report back

Answer (score 0):

I would create a pseudo element, absolutely position it and layer it on top of your nav.

Since this gradient is purely decorative, I would not be using an actual `html` element for it.

```css
.topnav {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav::after {
  pointer-events: none; /* ignore clicks */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+50,000000+50,000000+100&1+0,0+50,1+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div id="mytopnav" class="topnav">
  <a class="navitem" href="#">About</a>
  <a class="navitem" href="#">Packages</a>
  <a class="navitem" href="#">Features</a>
  <a class="navitem" href="#">Blog</a>
  <a class="navitem" href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good solution and works perfectly. This is my problem solved :) I managed to solve it initially but as the other user pointed out, support for CSS Masks are limited so it wasn't ideal

Comment: Or actually, I am unable to click past the :after element, despite the content="" declaration, so perhaps this solution won't work.

Comment: @Levande I added one more line to `css`, to ignore clicks on the decorative element.

Comment: Ah thank you, I will try this method, although I have managed to make it work with clipping, perhaps this method works better